# Writing to an iframe from NSTextView

Tags: javascript, cocoa, webkit

I have built a web based WYSIWYG editor, which Im accessing programatically from my cocoa application. At the moment I'm able to run scripts and retrieve the HTML from the iFrame in the editor, but I'm unable to send text from an NSTextView to the iFrame. Any ideas?

The editor is here http://www.alexmillsdesign.com/Developer/FernEngine/

Cheers
Alex Mills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert in this area but I have written sample code in the past that did something similar to this.  The approach I took was the following: in your Cocoa class where you want to update the text insert code similar to

```
WebScriptObject *webScriptObject = [_webView windowScriptObject];
id result = [webScriptObject callWebScriptMethod:@"setTableRows" withArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:fauxData]];
```

where fauxData is whatever you want to pass to JS, and in the JS source have something similar to

```
var mytable = document.getElementById("myTable");
var mytbody = document.getElementById("myTbody");
var docFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var myNewtbody = document.createElement("tbody");   
myNewtbody.id = "myTbody";

var trElem, tdElem, txtNode;
for(var j = 0; j < row_data.length; ++j) {
    trElem = document.createElement("tr");
    trElem.className = "tr" + (j%2);

    tdElem = document.createElement("td");
    tdElem.className = "col0";
    txtNode = document.createTextNode(row_data[j].lastName);
    tdElem.appendChild(txtNode);
    trElem.appendChild(tdElem);

    tdElem = document.createElement("td");
    tdElem.className = "col4";
    txtNode = document.createTextNode(row_data[j].firstName);
    tdElem.appendChild(txtNode);
    trElem.appendChild(tdElem);

    docFragment.appendChild(trElem);
}
myNewtbody.appendChild(docFragment);
mytable.replaceChild(myNewtbody, mytbody);
```

and of course your HTML should have something like

```
<table id="myTable">

<thead id="myThead">
<tr>
<th>Last</th>
<th>First</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody id="myTbody">
</tbody>

</table>
```

Obviously this fills in rows of data in a table, but updating text would be similar.